# Check For Null Attributes in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, json, handsontable

The Handsontable documentation states you can set your column's data to a nested attributes of an object like so

```
hot4 = new Handsontable(container4, {
    data: nestedObjects,
    colHeaders: true,
    columns: [
      {data: 'id'},
      {data: 'name.first'},
      {data: 'name.last'},
      {data: 'address'}
    ],
    minSpareRows: 1
  });
```

This works fine, but I can't seem to account for if the returned user's first name is null - I've tried the following

```
{data: function(e){ 
   if(e.name!== null) { 
      return 'name.first' 
   }  else {
      return 'Not Found'
   }},
```

However this will embed the actual string `name.first` into the cell, which is obviously wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Returning the event.object.attribute grabs the user's first name

`return e.name.first`